# How to debug R-Shiny code with VS Code

Tags: r, debugging, shiny, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Is there any way to debug [Shiny (R)](https://shiny.rstudio.com/) inside VS Code? I can easily debug Shiny apps inside [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/) but I like to code inside VS Code so looking for the way to debug R code inside VS Code.

Comment: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/rtvs/

Comment: RTVS is for Visual Studio I think.

Answer (score 2):

Seems, shiny can be debugged in VSCode using `browser`-statements

**Prerequisites**

- Setup this VSCode extensions ([VSCode R Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/r))

  - R (by Yuki Ueda)
  - R Debugger
- Use a default app structure (see docs of `appDir` when running `?shiny::runApp` for possible setups)
- Set your VSCode workspace to the R projects root (e.g. File -> Open Folder... -> myProject)

**Debugging**

- Set your breakpoints using `browser()` ([RStudio Article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html))
- Run R-Debugger in **Launch R-Workspace** mode
- Execute `shiny::runApp()` in the Debug Console as soon the Debugger pauses
- Your app should fire up in a browser and the breakpoints pause the execution

**Further Ressources**

- [VSCode Article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) on debugging (can be very helpfull)
- [Issue](https://github.com/ManuelHentschel/VSCode-R-Debugger/issues/162)  on this topic in the VSCode-R-Debugger repo

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to see plots or html (e.g. from plotly) when in debugging mode. I already had "httpgd" as plotting device enabled. The option says it also changes the corresponding R option `vsc.use_httpgd`, but I checked it was `NULL`. Setting it explicitly in my `.Rprofile` or also live in the debugging session allowed me to see plots again, e.g. via `print(plot(1:5))`.

```
# For your .Rprofile
options("vsc.use_httpgd" = TRUE)

# code to check if option is set
getOption("vsc.use_httpgd")
```